# How to High Chart plotLine Priority Change

Tags: highcharts

I'm using a high chart.
I want to change the plotLine like this.
Help me.[image]

```js
yAxis: {
min: 0,
max: 100,
             
title: {
    text: '비율(%)',
    align: 'middle'
},
plotLines: [{
    color: '#FF0000',
    width: 5,
    value: 80
}],
},
```

Comment: Could you, please, provide a jsfiddle of the full chart code

Comment: Set higher z-index for the plot line - http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.plotLines.zIndex, see [example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/3.1.1/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/plotlines-zindex-above-all/)

Comment: thanks my good man.